# Conversion of JSON date into Date

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, angular5

I have used Angular2 - 4.x and did not get any issue of date conversion but as I updated to Angular 5.x. I am getting following logical error:-

If I enter date upto 31 Dec 2009, following javascript method which was working well, now convert it to one date back. i.e   If enter, 1 Aug 2008, it shows 31 Jul 2008.

If date is in year 2010 or later, it works fine. Looking for a favorable response.

```
ToJavaScriptDate(value: any) 
{
    var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
    var results = pattern.exec(value);
    var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));

     return (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate() + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
    //or simple return 
    // return dt;
}
```

Comment: This is almost certainly a timezone issue. You are probably displaying the time in UTC time instead of your native timezone. Can you provide an example input to this function? What is `value`?

Comment: Thank you so much for response.
I came to know the issue, actually there was a data type ‘date’ rather than ‘datetime’, Now if I add only date, it store in server as ‘2008-08-01 00:00:00.000’ and it shows on html page one date back i.e 31 Jul 2008 and if I add   ‘2008-08-01 01:00:00.000’, it works fine. 
I am working with two business applications one is in Angular 4.x and second one is 5.x. First one is working well but second one has above mentioned issue. I just changed the data type and it is working well now. Thanks once again.